# the table still cannot be created. what is the problem?

Tags: java, android, logcat

This is my Database class

```
public class ProgramDbAdapter{

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE = "ProgramTitle";
public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_DATE = "ProgramDate";
public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_TIME = "ProgramTime";
public static final String KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL = "ProgramChannel";
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + "_id integer primary key autoincrement, " 
    + "ProgramTitle text, " + "ProgramDate varchar(20), "
    + "ProgramTime varchar(20), " + "ProgramChannel text)";
private static final String DATABASE_UPGRADE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_UPGRADE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
public ProgramDbAdapter open() throws SQLException{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mcontext);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public long CreateData(String ProgramTitle, String ProgramDate, String ProgramTime, String ProgramChannel){
    ContentValues initialvalues = new ContentValues();
    initialvalues.put(KEY_PROGRAM_TITLE, ProgramTitle);
    initialvalues.put(KEY_PROGRAM_DATE, ProgramDate);
    initialvalues.put(KEY_PROGRAM_TIME, ProgramTime);
    initialvalues.put(KEY_PROGRAM_CHANNEL, ProgramChannel);
    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialvalues);
}
}
```

This is my main class

```
public class Program extends ExpandableListActivity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDbHelper = new ProgramDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        mDbHelper.CreateData("a","a","a","a");
    }
}
```

when i call open() and createdata function, the logcat tell me `no such table:Program`. where is the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I cannot create this table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752694/why-i-cannot-create-this-table)

Comment: that one i solved which the problem was duplicate column, now this is the problem after i solve the duplicate column but still cannot create the table

Answer (score 3):

There is no varchar type in sqlite, see [here](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Use text instead.

Comment: you aren't forced to using text ... see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where 'DATABASE_TABLE' is coming from.

Also, you should use the "rawQuery()", "query()"-Methods or a "SQLiteStatement" to bind parameters into your SQL-Statement.

And last but not least, SQLite doesn't know any 'varchar'. Check here for all Data types: [Link](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: SQLite do know varchar ... see my answer

Comment: `private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Program";`

Answer (score 0):

varchar is translated to text ... 
from vladimir link:

> If the declared type of the column
>   contains any of the strings "CHAR",
>   "CLOB", or "TEXT" then that column has
>   TEXT affinity. Notice that the type
>   VARCHAR contains the string "CHAR" and
>   is thus assigned TEXT affinity.

problem is that u created db in first run and there was different Create statment ...

delete app data from android settings or change DATABASE_VERSION

Comment: Still, I'd rather use the 'TEXT'-Data type directly in the creating query.

Comment: so the table cannot be create because of the varchar?
yet, the DATABASE_VERSION will affect the result too?

Comment: no, you can use varchar, i said thah you ran your app before you added db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); to onCreate implementation (or you change table name in   DATABASE_CREATE) ... changing DATABASE_VERSION will reacreate databes ... onCreate is called only if database not exist ... you need to force recreation by changeng db version or deleting data

Comment: actually what is my problem? i not really understand?